# Implement app thinning in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7, on-demand-resources

My iOS application's size is quite bigger on app store. How can I lower achieve the [app thinning](http://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) so that application size get lower.

`Note`:-

1. I am already using Images.xcassets to put x/2x/3x images separately.
2. I also read this [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html) and take care of optimisation level build settings.
3. I am also using an 8-bit PNG instead of a 32-bit PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching app thining, bit code and on demand app resource from yesterday, Now I debug all these things and sharing my knowledge that I got from beautiful [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Managing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH4-SW1) with help of my sample project.

App thinning concept covers [bit code](http://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) and on-demand resource. I will discuss on-demand resource in detail below:-

**On-Demand Resources in iOS:-**
It is accessing the images/videos/.h/.m/swift file whenever needed (`Yes, on-demand resouring include source code files also`).

- Goto `Resource tags` setting in your target.
- Create a new `Tag`. It will appear under Download Only On demand.
- You can add .h, .m, .xassest, .png etc under various tags. You can also assign tag by selecting individual file [like this in file inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Art/ODR_Tags_Field_File_Inspector_2x.png).

Now comes the coding part ([my favourite site](http://pkc456.blogspot.com/)):-

```
NSBundleResourceRequest *resourceRequest;


#pragma mark - On demand resource
-(void)getOnDemandResource{
    NSSet *setOfTag = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"chair", nil];
    resourceRequest = [[NSBundleResourceRequest alloc]initWithTags:setOfTag];

    [resourceRequest conditionallyBeginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL resourcesAvailable) {
        if (!resourcesAvailable) {
//            resourceRequest.loadingPriority = 1;//set the downloading priority (0 - 1) , NSBundleResourceRequestLoadingPriorityUrgent

            [resourceRequest beginAccessingResourcesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (error) {
                    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.debugDescription preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                }else{
                    //// The associated resources are loaded
                }
            }];
        }else{
            // The associated resources are available
        }
    }];
}
```

End accessing the on demand resource when not in use(generally when game level changes)

```
#pragma mark - Remove access to on demand
-(void)endAccessToOnDemandResource{
    [resourceRequest endAccessingResources];
}
```

`NOTE:-` Don't forgot to [enable On_Demand_Resources in build setting](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Art/ODR_Enabling_ODR_2x.png).

```
EXAMPLE PROJECT:- I create a sample project and uploaded here:- [http://www.dropbox.com/s/edi5zj68a4wuguh/WebOnTab.zip?dl=0][6]
```

Please don't bother about autolayout in this project. My main focus is on demand resourcing/App thing.

**SUMMARY:-** Thus we can achieve `app thinning` by `on-demand resourcing` using above technique. Please also have a look at [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH2-SW1) which also describes about `tracking progress`, `priorities` of resourceRequests(`NSBundleResourceRequest`).

Comment: Does anyone know how to detect where the on demand resources are located after being downloaded? I'm trying to use them for my game witch doesn't use xcasset catalog. I want to download the textures and then use them as if they are the part of the initial bundle, but I need to know file's exact location.

Comment: I checked the apple documentation(https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSBundleResourceRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundleResourceRequest/initWithTags:bundle:), but still not able to find the location. So I put up the question at SO:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824601/how-to-detect-where-the-on-demand-resources-are-located-after-being-downloaded

Answer (score 1):

App slicing is [currently not working](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=092415a) until further notice. The only way to reduce your app size is currently to reduce the amount of assets included in the .ipa.

You could try using [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) if they make sense for your app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing useful link. I am also following on demand resources. Let me cross check again in the app.

Comment: I tried on demand resource and implement that in my project successfully. I also shared a detail answer and sample project in my answer. Thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand App thinning, it is all done by Apple. It looks at what is the target device, and the required images and stuff will be provided to the user automatically.

If you would like get thinner app, maybe refactoring is the topic you should look at.

Comment: Yep right. It is taken care by Apple. But there may be some imp points which developer need to taken care of as I listed in my question. Do you have idea of tagging, which is related to On-Demand Resources?